# Adding Timer to iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying add a feature where On certain push, my timer will be started and even the app is close the timer will continue. Lets say my Points were 10 and now timer started. Once i close the app, maybe next time if i open the app the

1- If before 20 min it will show a count down timer running

2- if after 20 min at app again start it will add point to 10.

Now what Kind of timer or class can help me do this?

Regards

Comment: while closing the app just stop the timer .....

Comment: Like Mountain Lion said: Use NSTimeInterval to set a timestamp and compare it to the new time when reentering the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTimer` will not continue more than **600** seconds even if your app is in **background**, rest terminating the app.

**you can rather do this:**

```
NSString *prevTimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 
                         [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
```

store this `prevTimestamp` in `NSUserDefaults`, and when coming back to the app,

```
NSString *nowTimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 
                         [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
```

time difference will be `[nowTimestamp floatValue] - [prevTimestamp floatValue]`

Answer (score 1):

In your delegate for app terminiation save the time in NSUserdefaults and while you laucnch the app read it back and go on to add the time on that.

Answer (score 0):

Within your applicationdelegate, you have these functions:

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application;
```

and

```
-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;
```

From these functions you can track time through something like this:

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    backgroundTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]; 
}

-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    double timetoAppend = [[NSDate Date] timeIntervalSince1970] - backgroundTime];

    // from here you need to add the timetoAppend to your own variable

}
```